# Programmatically add value to custom field based on custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called `"Products"` and I have a taxonomy called `"Price range"` and a custom field called `"product-number"`.

In price range I have a term called `"250 kr", "450kr", "580kr" and so on.`

What I need is to have a way to add data to the custom field based on which term they are in.

**Example of what I want:**

All products in the `"250 kr"` taxonomy term need to have `200-"unique-number"` added to the `"product-number"` custom field created from Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

```
So 200-1, 200-2, 200-3 etc. and in the 450 I need 400-1, 400-2 and so on.
```

I need it to do it for all the previous created products, and also when creating new. So when creating a new product, it needs to look at what taxonomy it is in and then what the previous "product-number" was.

So if the last product is created in the `"250 kr"` term and has the product number 200-68 the next product I create needs to automatically get 200-69 in the `"product number"` custom field.

I've looked at auto-infringement in ACF:

> https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/need-help-for-auto-increment-field-with-update_field/

I've tried adding this with some terms, but does not work.

```
add_option('ebo_dernier_num_club','3005','','no');
function ebo_renseigne_num_affiliation($value, $post_id, $field) {
    if (! $value && get_post_type($post_id)=='club_type') {
        $last_num = (int) get_option('ebo_dernier_num_club', '3000');
        $last_num++;
        update_option('ebo_dernier_num_club', $last_num);
        $value = $last_num;
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=numero_affiliation', 'ebo_renseigne_num_affiliation', 10, 3);
```

I expect it to auto increment based on the taxonomy term and previous products created.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function.
update_field($selector, $value, [$post_id]);

You can follow this link: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Comment: @Foarm Mehta Thank you for your answer. I don't really know how to implement your answer into a functioning line of code for my specific example.

Comment: @kongen, please go through this link: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/update-field-programmatically/